# Identifying a style of (possibly) gospel funk?

Tags: identify-this-genre, funk

Back in the 1990s I developed a fondness for the big bouncy synth brass sound of the gospel funk segments - for want of a better term - in the *[Joyful Joyful](https://youtu.be/OaEH1e_DLm0?t=84)* number at the end of *Sister Act 2*. Then it sort of faded into the background for a couple of decades until I listened to the 44 Remix of Lin-Manuel Miranda's *One Last Time*, which goes into a lovely [funky break](https://youtu.be/8T3l3bcNuqs?t=179) right after President Obama's recitation in a very similar style.

Specifically I'm looking for the style characterised by funk bass, punchy brass stings (possibly synth brass), gospel instrumentation (ideally with Hammond organ) and choir, and a fast shuffle.

But I can't seem to find any other tunes in that style. What genre is it really, and are there any other good songs like it? I keep thinking of it as gospel funk, but that's a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best described as **uptempo 90s gospel** music. This is what mainstream gospel sounded like around the time *Sister Act 2* came out. This mix below is a good example --I've set it to start in the middle of John P. Kee's "Show Up." Kirk Franklin's "Stomp!" (at the beginning of the mix) is another great song from the era, although perhaps a little less characteristic.

Gospel funk is a real genre, but it's more of a 70s and early 80s sound. "Like a Ship" is probably the classic of the genre: